# Existing table error when run migrate for databases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I had write my own command for migrate all database from list.
I change database connection by changing settings in config with `config()`.
My mechanism make migrate for all database switch database and use `Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations', '--database' => 'mysql']);`

It works localy on my pc but when I run it on serwer I have that error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(191) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

In different databases was imported same database dump but only one migration process end with success.

Comment: Maybe your table `migrations` does not exist on your server or isn't up to date?

Comment: They are existing and what is more one database do not have problem with migration. All database have same tables and data from one database dump.